# Cookie issue with Java client using HttpURLConnection + Node.js / Express webserver

Tags: java, node.js, cookies, express

I have a Java client trying to connect to an Express.js webserver serving content with cookies.  The express server works fine on the browser (it receives session cookies), but not with my Java client.   The Java client shows that the `Set-Cookie` field on the response header is `null`.

It's almost certainly a Java problem.  I have inspected the network traffic (using wireshark) and it shows that the Express.js webserver is serving cookies as expected.

I have the following Java code:

```
package mine;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpsClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

        URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8888");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        String headerName=null;
        for (int i=1; (headerName = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
            System.out.println(headerName + ": " + conn.getHeaderField(i));
        }        
    }
}
```

The output from the above code:

```
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4535
ETag: "309029400"
Set-Cookie: null
Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2013 04:40:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Below is the express.js / node.js code:

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var mongoStore  = require('connect-mongo')(express);

app.configure(function(){

    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.errorHandler());

    app.use(express.session({
        store: new mongoStore({
            url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sessions'
        }),
        secret: 'asdasdfasdfasdfasdfa',
        maxAge  : new Date(Date.now() + 24*3600*1000 * 365),
        expires : new Date(Date.now() + 24*3600*1000 * 365)
    }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('ok', 200);
});


var http        = require('http');
http.createServer(app).listen(8888, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + 8888);
});
```

Am I missing something here?  Does Java have a different way of handling session cookies?

Comment: Have you thought about using Apache HttpClient? I have been able to use it with cookies in the past. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Comment: @Catchwa, thanks a lot!!  It works with your suggestion.  I spent a whole day trying to figure this one out.  I still wonder why the above does not work.